# SetWindowTextA update value freeze when called many times

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have a set of labels (63) which change the value every 100 ms. labels values are stored in `orderedTablePressure` array. in the main loop I call the following function each 100 ms to update labels values. but when I iterate in the loop until 63 the labels freeze within a short amont of time (not changing value), when I iterate to 20, the freezing takes more time to happen but it happen anyway, when I iterate to 10 it takes minutes to freeze and then freeze (labels values no longer updated).
what could be the problem? could it be a memory issue, is there any free objects functions I should call?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

    sprintf(window_text, "%d", orderedTablePressure[j]);
    GetWindowRect(hWndLabel[j], &rect);
    SetWindowTextA(hWndLabel[j], window_text);
}
```

---

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    ........

case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
        DWORD CtrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);
        int green = (255 * orderedTablePressure[CtrlID - 1000] / 4096);
        assert(0 <= green <= 255);
        green = (green - 128) * 2;
        clrLabelBkGnd = RGB(255, green, 0);

        hDC = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
        SetBkColor(hDC, clrLabelBkGnd);
        return (INT_PTR)hBrushLabel[green];
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Just a note: `assert(0 <= green <= 255);` has no meaning, the expression is always true. The `0 <= green` part is evaluated to either true or false, then promoted to integer for compare with 255 (as either 1 or 0), and it's always less than 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is working, but nothing gets re-painted, most likely you have a resource leak, and you exhausted your 10,000 handles "allowance". The easy check is to look in the Task Manager, **GDI objects** column - is the value for your process 10,000? If yes - look for created but not released GDI objects in your painting function. Or post it here - will look together.